# phonegap app not works with jquery and XMLHttpRequest in blackberry

Tags: jquery, json, blackberry, cordova

My phonegap application run perfect in andriod and iphone.

But its not works on blackberry when i will remove jquery all code runs perfect all json data display without format.

At same time if i will enable jquery then all json data gone.

I have used jquery XMLHttpRequest for json.

Any advice????

Comment: Are you using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue.
use http://www.freelancephp.net/en/simpleajax-small-ajax-javascript-object/  instead of jquery ajax.

worked for me..